# Canvas disappearing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've written a simple script in JS. When I put hit it into html document (at the bottom of body tag), it works fine. When I try to put it into external document and I link it, script runs but the canvas element disappears (just checked: it works when I put the script in the bottom, but not in head tag).
This version works:

```js
   var c = document.getElementById("canvasId");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 
   var text = "Nazwa pomiaru";
   var boxWidth = 200;
   var boxHeight = 200;
   var minValue = 0;
   var maxValue = 100;
   var midValue = (Math.abs(minValue) + Math.abs(maxValue))/2;
   var unit = "%";
   var indicWidth = 50;
   var indicHeight = 0.6 * boxHeight;
   var textPosition = 0.875;
   var leftMargin = 0.375;
   var topMargin = 0.15;
   var bottomMargin = 0.75;
   var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
   var warningTop = 90;
   var dangerTop = 95;
   var warningBottom = 10;
   var dangerBottom = 5;
   var thresholdTrasparency = 0.6;
   var strokeColor = "#CCCCCC";
   var valueColor = "#993333";
   var warningColor = "#ff6600";
   var dangerColor = "#cc0000";
   var textColor = "#000000";
   var textColor2 = "#ffffff";
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.fillText((maxValue + unit), (leftMargin * boxWidth - ctx.measureText(maxValue + unit).width-1), (topMargin * boxHeight + 3), (boxWidth / 4)); //draw a maxValue
   ctx.fillText((midValue + unit), (leftMargin * boxWidth - ctx.measureText(midValue + unit).width-1), ((topMargin + bottomMargin) / 2 * boxHeight + 3), (boxWidth / 4)); //draw a midValue
   ctx.fillText((minValue + unit), (leftMargin * boxWidth - ctx.measureText(minValue + unit).width-1), (bottomMargin * boxHeight + 3), (boxWidth / 4)); //draw a minValue  
   ctx.fillText(text, ((boxWidth - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2), (textPosition * boxHeight), (textPosition * boxWidth)); //type a text
   ctx.lineWidth = "0";
   ctx.globalAlpha = thresholdTrasparency;
   if (warningTop !== 0 || warningBottom !== 0) {
    ctx.fillStyle = warningColor;
    ctx.fillRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight), indicWidth, ((100 - warningTop) * (indicHeight / 100))); //draw a warningTop
    ctx.fillRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight + (100 - warningBottom) * (indicHeight / 100)), indicWidth, (indicHeight - (100 - warningBottom) * (indicHeight / 100))); //draw a warningBottom 
   }
   if (dangerTop !== 0 || dangerBottom !== 0) {
    ctx.fillStyle = dangerColor;
    ctx.fillRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight), indicWidth, ((100 - dangerTop) * (indicHeight / 100))); //draw a dangerTop
    ctx.fillRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight + (100 - dangerBottom) * (indicHeight / 100)), indicWidth, (indicHeight - (100 - dangerBottom) * (indicHeight / 100))); //draw a dangerBottom 
   }
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
   ctx.fillStyle = valueColor;
   ctx.fillRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight + (100 - value) * (indicHeight / 100)), indicWidth, (indicHeight - (100 - value) * (indicHeight / 100))); //draw a valueIndicator
   if (value <= 47) {
    ctx.fillStyle= textColor;
   }
   else {
    ctx.fillStyle = textColor2;
   }
   ctx.fillText(value, ((boxWidth - ctx.measureText(value).width) / 2), (boxHeight / 2));
   ctx.shadowBlur = 6;
   ctx.shadowColor = "#000000";
   ctx.lineWidth="2";
   ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
   ctx.strokeRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight), indicWidth, indicHeight); //draw a rectangle
   ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
   document.write(value);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Slider</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvasId" style="border: 3px solid; background: #ffffff;" width="200px" height="200px">
  No support.
  </canvas>
  <script src="canvas.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

This version does not work:

```js
function draw () {
   var c = document.getElementById("canvasId");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 
   var text = "Nazwa pomiaru";
   var boxWidth = 200;
   var boxHeight = 200;
   var minValue = 0;
   var maxValue = 100;
   var midValue = (Math.abs(minValue) + Math.abs(maxValue))/2;
   var unit = "%";
   var indicWidth = 50;
   var indicHeight = 0.6 * boxHeight;
   var textPosition = 0.875;
   var leftMargin = 0.375;
   var topMargin = 0.15;
   var bottomMargin = 0.75;
   var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
   var warningTop = 90;
   var dangerTop = 95;
   var warningBottom = 10;
   var dangerBottom = 5;
   var thresholdTrasparency = 0.6;
   var strokeColor = "#CCCCCC";
   var valueColor = "#993333";
   var warningColor = "#ff6600";
   var dangerColor = "#cc0000";
   var textColor = "#000000";
   var textColor2 = "#ffffff";
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.fillText((maxValue + unit), (leftMargin * boxWidth - ctx.measureText(maxValue + unit).width-1), (topMargin * boxHeight + 3), (boxWidth / 4)); //draw a maxValue
   ctx.fillText((midValue + unit), (leftMargin * boxWidth - ctx.measureText(midValue + unit).width-1), ((topMargin + bottomMargin) / 2 * boxHeight + 3), (boxWidth / 4)); //draw a midValue
   ctx.fillText((minValue + unit), (leftMargin * boxWidth - ctx.measureText(minValue + unit).width-1), (bottomMargin * boxHeight + 3), (boxWidth / 4)); //draw a minValue  
   ctx.fillText(text, ((boxWidth - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2), (textPosition * boxHeight), (textPosition * boxWidth)); //type a text
   ctx.lineWidth = "0";
   ctx.globalAlpha = thresholdTrasparency;
   if (warningTop !== 0 || warningBottom !== 0) {
    ctx.fillStyle = warningColor;
    ctx.fillRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight), indicWidth, ((100 - warningTop) * (indicHeight / 100))); //draw a warningTop
    ctx.fillRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight + (100 - warningBottom) * (indicHeight / 100)), indicWidth, (indicHeight - (100 - warningBottom) * (indicHeight / 100))); //draw a warningBottom 
   }
   if (dangerTop !== 0 || dangerBottom !== 0) {
    ctx.fillStyle = dangerColor;
    ctx.fillRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight), indicWidth, ((100 - dangerTop) * (indicHeight / 100))); //draw a dangerTop
    ctx.fillRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight + (100 - dangerBottom) * (indicHeight / 100)), indicWidth, (indicHeight - (100 - dangerBottom) * (indicHeight / 100))); //draw a dangerBottom 
   }
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
   ctx.fillStyle = valueColor;
   ctx.fillRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight + (100 - value) * (indicHeight / 100)), indicWidth, (indicHeight - (100 - value) * (indicHeight / 100))); //draw a valueIndicator
   if (value <= 47) {
    ctx.fillStyle= textColor;
   }
   else {
    ctx.fillStyle = textColor2;
   }
   ctx.fillText(value, ((boxWidth - ctx.measureText(value).width) / 2), (boxHeight / 2));
   ctx.shadowBlur = 6;
   ctx.shadowColor = "#000000";
   ctx.lineWidth="2";
   ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
   ctx.strokeRect((leftMargin * boxWidth), (topMargin * boxHeight), indicWidth, indicHeight); //draw a rectangle
   ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
   document.write(value); 
};

window.onload = draw;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Slider</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvasId" style="border: 3px solid; background: #ffffff;" width="200px" height="200px">
  No support.
  </canvas>
  <script src="canvas.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The second version someway hides canvas tag but the text appears (so the script works).

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: you don't get any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: The problem is the `document.write(value)`. If you remove that it works in both versions. On the second version is overwriting all the body.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida, you should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your canvas (and the entire document, for that matter) disappears is because you are using **document.write**. In the first snippet, you're writing to the document before it *closes the stream*. In the case of the second snippet, you're only executing that code after **window.onLoad**, at which point the document stream is closed.

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open which will clear the document.
>    - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

#### The solution(s) would be:

1) Don't use document.write - If you need to write to the document, place an HTML element on the page, then write to that element:

```
 // html:
 <html>
    ...
    <body>
       <p id="output"></p>
    </body>
 </html>

 // Javascript
 // ...
 var el = document.getDocumentById('output');
 el.textContent = value
```

2) Don't call document.write after page has loaded (as you do in your first snippet)

Personally, I would never use document.write, as you might run into issues such as what you describe.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `document.write(value)` that is overwriting all body.

Why?

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open which will clear the document.

So, on your second you are doing it on `window.onload` calling `document.open` and clearing the document. While on your first version you don't call it `onload`.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling
>   document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls
>   document.open which will clear the document

Source: [Document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

[Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/157873)